# How to set the text to a td in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set a text value to a `td` using Jquery

I have tried :

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td.cmd_old').text() = "naveen";
```

but this is not helping

Comment: `text` is a function that takes the new text as a parameter, use as: `.text("naveen")`. Besides that, `children` returns an array of child items, so you want to iterate over that array and call `text` function on that

Comment: `.text()` will return the elements text, while `.text(“tree”)` well set the elements text to “tree”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the desired text as parameter so it will be something like `.text("YOUR TEXT")` instead, e.g :

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td.cmd_old').text("naveen");
```

Take a look to [`.text()` official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thank you so much and one more question how to get a textbox value inside a table on clicking button in the same TR